# Tell Lion to Ignore Device

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, osx-lion, vmware-fusion

Host machine: OSX Lion. Guest Machine: Windows XP inside VMWare Fusion.

I have a Samsung modem that I am trying to upgrade via VMWare Fusion (upgrade software is Windows only, my computer is running Lion). I've done this before on Snow Leopard, but now with Lion, OSX takes over the modem (the top right of the shot shows the OSX recognition of modem):

[image]

The screenshot shows how OSX is "recognizing" the modem. How do I get it to stop? Otherwise the message from Fusion is:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Fusion installed anymore (I prefer VirtualBox), but I know there's a way to allow pass-through of USB devices in both. Investigate that option in the help file.

Comment: Hi @RandolphWest when I turn on pass through, Fusion informs (as in the second graphic) that the device is already being handled by the host. What I need to do is inform OSX somehow not to do this.

Comment: I'm with you now. Apparently I can't read. Perhaps if you disable the device in the Network Preferences window by deleting it?

Comment: @RandolphWest I wish, but it's not showing up in Network Preferences. Ironically, in Windows I would know what to do ;)

Comment: @RandolphWest it seems to be `/System/Library/Extensions/IOSerialFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleWWANSupport.kext/Contents/Resources/wwand` but yet when I try to kill it it gets another pid and comes back to life. How do I stop it?

Comment: And `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOSerialFamily.kext` says it's in use or retained. Ugh.

Comment: Does `kextstat` print something about `AppleWWANSupport.kext`? Can you `kextunload` that?

Comment: @DanielBeck if I do `sudo kextstat | grep -i wwan` I get nothing. I mean, not even sure that't kext I want, but it does look suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Start up the virtual machine first. Then plug in the device.